Excel Chart for Arc On and Arc Off
I wanted to inquire about how could I create an excel chart that represents a machine's Arc On and Arc Off in a time scale.
Make it so that an Arc On would represent a signal value of "1" and when Arc Off would represent a signal value of "0". Arc On and Arc Off is in form of TIME interval with durations (e.g. 5 seconds, 10 seconds, etc)
The table that I create for example
My expectation would be something like these
green represents the interval of the Arc On and Arc Off
This so that I can distinguish when is the machine is being used and when the machine is IDLE.

This might give some pointers https://exceloffthegrid.com/variable-width-column-charts-histograms-excel/
